# Symfony2 - KnpMenuBundle: Fatal exception in service container

Tags: php, symfony

I'm using the [KnpMenuBundle](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=knpmenubundle&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB0QFjAA&url=https://github.com/knplabs/KnpMenuBundle&ei=ggDaTp3vG46o8AOmtJHWDQ&usg=AFQjCNHt1lblRNmWCbw3uCPQmSVUJ0YDmA) in my application, and I have followed their instructions to set up my menu as a service.

Whenever I try to render the menu using the twig helper function

`{{ knp_menu_render('VhotoHelperBundle:MenuBuilder:mainMenu') }}`

It gives me the following error...

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Vhoto\HelperBundle\Menu\MenuBuilder::__construct() must implement interface Knp\Menu\FactoryInterface, none given

My `services.yml` file is present in my bundle's `Resources/config` directory, and has the following contents:

```
services:
  vhoto.menu_builder:
    class: Vhoto\HelperBundle\Menu\MenuBuilder
    arguments: ["@knp_menu.factory"]

  vhoto.menu.main:
    class: Knp\Menu\MenuItem
    factory_service: vhoto.menu_builder
    factory_method: createMainMenu
    arguments: ["@request"]
    scope: request
    tags:
      - { name: knp_menu.menu, alias: main }
```

I have created an extension class in my bundle's `DependencyInjection` directory:

```
class VhotoHelperExtension extends Extension
{
    public function load(array $config, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $loader = new YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
        $loader->load('services.yml');
    }
}
```

And have updated my bundle's build method to register the extension:

```
public function build(ContainerBuilder $container)
{
    parent::build($container);
    $container->registerExtension(new VhotoHelperExtension());
}
```

What I can't figure out is why my `arguments: ["@knp_menu.factory"]` config isn't taking effect, am I missing something in the extension class? I read the chapter on [Exposing Semantic Configuration for bundles](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/extension.html) but it didn't shed any light.

EDIT: Okay, just realised that I don't need to manually register my extension in my bundle class. Removed that code from my app now but still getting the same exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay after re-reading the basic setup, seems everything was right apart from my twig function call.

```
{{ knp_menu_render('main') }}
```