# Symfony2: KnpMenuBundle: The menu "main" is not defined exception in rendering template

Tags: symfony

I'm using Symfony2 with the KnpMenuBundle installed as submodules and using the *service* configuration method.

When calling the page with the menu in the layout using:

```
{{ knp_menu_render('main') }}
```

I get the error:

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("The
>   menu "main" is not defined.") in CCGlobalBundle::layout.html.twig

My services.yml file (is parsed in the load() method of the CCGlobalExtension.php bundle class) seems to be being called as intentional errors in it cause further code errors:

```
# src/CC/GlobalBundle/Resources/Config/services.yml
services:
cc_global.menu_builder:
    class: CC\GlobalBundle\Menu\MenuBuilder
    arguments: ["@knp_menu.factory"]

cc_global.menu.main:
    class: Knp\Menu\MenuItem # the service definition requires setting the class
    factory_service: cc_global.menu_builder
    factory_method: createMainMenu
    arguments: ["@request"]
    scope: request # needed as we have the request as a dependency here
    tags:
        - { name: knp_menu.menu, alias: main }
```

And my main /app/config/config.yml file contains the knp_menu: directive:

```
knp_menu:
twig: 
    template: knp_menu.html.twig
templating: false # if true, enables the helper for PHP templates
default_renderer: twig # The renderer to use, list is also available by default
```

There is the same question but no specific solution that worked here: [Symfony2 - KnpMenuBundle: Fatal exception in service container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8367211/symfony2-knpmenubundle-fatal-exception-in-service-container)

Does anyone know what could be the problem (also checked the Git issues) for this?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this issue, but found this exception "**The menu 'main' is not defined**" was thrown *because I had not registered the service* of MyCompany/MyBundle/Resources/config/services.yml in app/config/config.yml. **Fixed like this:**

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html

```
# app/config/config.yml
imports:
    - { resource: "@MyCompanyMyBundle/Resources/config/services.yml" }
```

Comment: If you follow the service installation instructions verbatim in the [KNP - "Creating Menus as Services" docs](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpMenuBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/menu_service.md) you could easily end up with this error. Thanks for sharing your answer. It helped me reconcile this very quickly (though really I should have known that I hadn't imported the config from my bundle to the main app - silly thing to forget).

Comment: thank you for your comment, i was trying to add menu as a service, ended up having to create a new services.yml, inside app/config, and no wonder, thanks to your comment since it was a new file, it wasnt being read yet.

Answer (score 0):

A code error was introduced to the Git. The git issue is here: https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpMenuBundle/issues/89

The change for others looking was line 28 of the /vendor/bundles/Knp/Bundle/MenuBundle/DependencyInjection/KnpMenuExtension.php should have read:

```
$container->getDefinition(sprintf('knp_menu.menu_provider.%s', $builder))->addTag('knp_menu.provider');
```

while the incorrect code read:

```
$container->getDefinition(sprintf('knp_menu.menu_provider.%s', $builder))->addTag('knp_menu.menu_provider');
```

Note '***provider***' vs. '***menu_provider***'